# java editor & code folding

Tags: java, visual-studio, editor, syntax-highlighting

It's been a few years since I barked up this tree, but this fall I have to have a look at java again for coursework. Coming from a C# and .net world here at work I'm sort of spoiled with a good ide, code folding etc :)

So here goes: Does it even exist a good ide for java yet?

Please don't say netbeans or eclipse ;) Last time I coded java, the only thing that sort of cut it was plain old .bat files and ultraedit.

Comment: You wont get better IDEs than eclipse or netbeans.. Only thing is it takes little time to get used to it. Dont avoid ECLIPSE

Comment: @Rp- Yes you can get better IDEs than Eclipse and NetBeans if you are willing to pay for it: IntelliJ IDEA (or use the Community Edition). But that is also a **Personal** preference just like yours :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at IntelliJ IDEA http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll have a look at it!

Answer (score 1):

Both Eclipse and NetBeans have Code folding, as well as a ton of other awesome features. When was the last time you actually used them?

To answer your original question about an IDE for Java: **Eclipse** and **NetBeans**, a close tie for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need code folding, limited autocomplete and syntax highlighting you can use notepad++. However, I myself prefer a more intelligent ide like intellij IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ever used [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) (plugin for VS) and like its functionality then you should take a look at [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) since the same company developed the [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). Tons of good stuff!